# why is the OR being ignored in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, where-clause, sql-in

I have the following Handshake table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Handshake](
    [Report Year] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Update Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Process Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Rejects?] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

If i run this query,

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM [dbo].[Handshake]
WHERE [Status] <> 'Loading' OR [Status] <> 'Processing' OR [Status] <> 'Processed' OR [Status] <> 'Process Failed'
ORDER BY [Update Time] DESC
```

i expect anything indicated in the WHERE clause NOT to be returned, but it is!!
For example, `Processed` record should NOT have been returned!!

This is what i get:

[image: record]

Sample Data

```
Report Year Status      Update Time             Process Time            Rejects?
2020 8+4    Processed   2020-10-09 16:58:05.610 2020-10-09 17:20:05.000 NULL
2020 8+4    Processed   2020-10-09 16:22:06.343 2020-10-09 16:53:26.000 NULL
2020 5+7    Processed   2020-09-29 18:09:00.000 2020-10-09 16:04:04.000 TRUE
2020 6+6    Failed  2020-09-29 17:21:00.000 NULL    NULL
2020 5+7    Processed   2020-09-29 15:54:00.000 2020-10-09 16:04:04.000 NULL
```

Comment: If you say, "I want a car that is _not red_ **or** _not blue_" - surely you mean "I want a car that is not red **and** is not blue." Otherwise either a red car or a blue car would still pass your test.

Comment: @AaronBertrand makes sense

Comment: Yeah, thiis might not be the most intuitive. This reminds me of DeMorgan's law in propositional logic. Specifically, `not (A and B) = not A or not B`. In this case, `not (Loading and Processing ...)`.

Comment: @PatrickBacon its very tricky, its like its right but at the same time its wrong lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `AND`, not `OR`:

```
WHERE [Status] <> 'Loading' 
  AND [Status] <> 'Processing' 
  AND [Status] <> 'Processed' 
  AND [Status] <> 'Process Failed'
```

You could also express this with `not in`:

```
WHERE [Status] NOT IN ('Loading', 'Processing', 'Processed', 'Process Failed')
```

Comment: perfect!! you saved the day :)